# Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility View sends incorrect User Agent String

Tags: windows, browser, internet-explorer, user-agent

My user agent string in IE 10 Compatibility View is incorrect.  It still sends a user agent string that identifies as IE 10.  This prevents pages rendering in IE7 the way they should.

**Internet Explorer 10:**

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)

**Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility View (Normal):**

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.2)

**Internet Explorer 10 Compatibility View (My Actual):**

> Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; MS-RTC LM 8; InfoPath.2)

I've tried disabling add-ons (via the UI and the command line).  I've tested this on other machines and I am not getting the same results.

What's going on here?  Why is this happening?